# which algorithm GNU make uses to travel the dependency graph?

Tags: graphs

Make is a very common English word and consequently I cannot find the answer using google.

I am writing a script to automate all the data generation process, which resembles what GNU make does.

I am curious to know which type of algorithm GNU make uses under the hood. I suppose it is some sort topological sort with BFS/DFS. Can anyone provide any insight or provide a reference ? thanks

Comment: found this one actually, the author mentioned that it is dfs
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/85279/how-does-make-scons-manage-dependency-graph-and-figure-out-which-file-need-to-be

Comment: Try searching for gmake instead of make. You can easily find the source code, for example.